# `index.json.js` endpoint - svelte kit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Using sveltekit I have and `index.svelte` file and I'm trying to call an endpoint called `index.json.js` like that:

```js
<script context="module">
  export async function load({ params, fetch }) {
    const response = await fetch('/index.json');
    // ...
  }
</script>
```

Instead of calling the `index.json.js` endpoint, this calls the less specific `[page].json.js` endpoint. (When renaming the file to `foo.json.js` and `await fetch('/foo.json')`, it works).

I couldn't find anything about reserved keywords in the sveltekit documentation, so is there a reason for this behavior?

Thenks for helping me understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at how the `index` gets contracted [in examples](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#endpoints-standalone-endpoints), I tried just removing it like this:

```js
await fetch('/.json');
```

It seems to call the correct endpoint that way.